# mysql set auto increment to 1 with foreign key

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want to set auto increment to 1 by below command, but it doesn't works:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

I searched and found out that I should use `TRUNCATE TABLE`. But this command fails due to foreign key constraint. Any idea?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you actually want to remove your data?

Comment: @Phil I want to set auto increment value to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever need `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` you are probably misusing `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` is designed to provide unique keys, nothing more.  If you need it to be "1", you should invent your own mechanism; do not trust `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Would you care to explain your purpose?  Perhaps we can help you find a suitable workaround.  (No "setting it to 1" is not the purpose, it is your attempted solution to some higher purpose.  Step back.)

Comment: Just because I have done a lot of tests, my id is now a very big number before production level. But anyway not very important. Thanks.

Comment: Several things can "burn" ids, making then grow faster than desired:  `INSERT IGNORE`, IODKU, `REPLACE`, etc.  [_This_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) discusses a way to avoid such during batch normalization.